# Do I need "where" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage

> He was sleeping in the same bed (where) his girlfriend had died last
>   year.

Both versions sound okay to me. Is "where" necessary or unnecessary? Why?

Comment: These are both relative constructions. The version with "where" is okay, since "where" means "in which", but it is less likely to be heard than the alternant without "where", though a preposition is required: "He was sleeping in the same bed his girlfriend had died **in** last year".

Comment: Does "where" mean the same thing as "in which"? I don't think it does. "Where" is general location, while "in which" is one specific location from a group. I could be wrong, but "where" sounds wrong to me here.

Comment: @jmartindill Yes, the "in" component is contributed by "where" together with its spatial location function, cf. "This is the house where (in which) I was born": [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/where)

Comment: @BillJ you're right, I stand corrected. "In which" is more formal, but in informal speech "where" seems to be just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Where is considered appropriate here, just informal. "Where" might just seem strange to me because it's a bed and not a building or something, but I think it's fine.

[See this article](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/where-versus-in-which?page=1) for a full discussion.

Original answer below:

I don't think "where" is the proper word here. To me, "in which" sounds much more appropriate, as in

> He was sleeping in the same bed **in which** his girlfriend had died last year.

I can't tell you exactly why, but I would use "where" if there isn't an object.

> He was sleeping where his girlfriend had died.

Alternatively, you could write it as

> He was sleeping in the same bed his girlfriend had died **in** last year.

or

> He was sleeping in the same bed **that** his girlfriend had died **in** last year.

**EDIT**

To clarify about why "where" seems wrong to me:

If I say, "He is sleeping there", you might ask, "Where?" So, you can write

> He is sleeping where she had died.

If I say, "He is sleeping in this bed", the question isn't, "where?", the question is, "which bed?"  So, you can write,

> He is sleeping in the bed which she had died in.